# Search for cells that are highlighted in a column then link them to another sheet's column

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing a hide and show columns using a button, and this button will only work when it detects highlighted cells which are linked to another sheet's column.

```
Example:
Worksheets(A)

COLUMN A
ID
CUSTOMER
PRIORITY
TIME

Worksheets(B)

A      B            C          D
ID    CUSTOMER     PRIORITY   TIME
```

If a cell is highlighted (cell's background) from SheetA then match it to SheetB's column, after that hide the entire column selected.

This is the code for when the user select the cell, it will be highlighted:
[image: This is the code for when the user select the cell, it will be highlighted.]]

And this is where I'm stuck.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Actually i have solved the problem, as simple as this
```

If Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
Worksheets(2).Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = True End If